# Fastest way to solve the divisibility of numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a program in which in which 4 numbers are input n,a,b,c

how many number exists which are less than or equal to n and are divisible by a ,b or c .

Sample input case - 
15 2 3 5
output 
11

Here n = 15 , a= 2, b=3,c = 5 The number which are divisible by a ,b, or c are 2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,14,15 i.e 11 numbers , so output is 11

I have tried with this solution but the time is exceeding

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long divisibilty (long long a, long long c, long long b, long long n ) {
    long long temp, min,count = 0,i;
    temp = (a < b)    ? a : b;
    min =  (c < temp) ? c : temp;

    for(i=min;i<=n;i++){
        if( (i % a == 0)  || (i % b == 0) || (i % c == 0) ){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;

}

int main() {

    int t_i;

        long long n;
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        long long a;
        scanf("%lld", &a);
        long long b;
        scanf("%lld", &b);
        long long c;
        scanf("%lld", &c);

        long long out_ = divisibilty(a, c, b, n);
        printf("%lld", out_);

}
```

Can anyone help me with a better solution

Comment: Explainthe Timeisexceeding. How long does it take for a given sample input?

Comment: So your solution "works", but you just want to optimize it to get below a certain time?

Comment: yeah i want to optimize it

Comment: It is  taking more than 3 seconds

Comment: @Nishtha I think your question belongs in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you absolutely have to use `long long`s?

Comment: You are trying to brute-force the solution.  Many of these type of problems require you to think of a more efficient way to solve the problem.  Trying to optimise the code is the last thing you should attempt.

Comment: yeah because the range of number can be upto 10 ^ 9

Comment: 10^9  fits signed 32 bit integer

Comment: 4 byte `int` can hold up to ~2*10^9, so you are fine here. Try using `int`s instead - working on larger data types takes a little longer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't have memory issue I am problem with time. And I know i am using brute force .That is why I am asking over here for a better solution

Comment: This can be done without using division/mod at all.

Comment: Lee Daniel Crocker   - How it can be done?

Comment: Is it a code challenge you are trying to participate in?

Comment: It was a coding challenge i participated few months back so looking for a better solution

Comment: @Fureeish is right. using long long in 32 bit environment has time penalty as well.

Comment: You really shouldn't have to do any division.  Count how many multiple of `a`, `b`, and `c` exist below `n`.  Add that up and then cancel out any common multiples.

Comment: How about doing the reverse of what you are doing. As you progress, the space between multiples of those numbers are going to get bigger and bigger and you skip lots of numbers, so multiply `a`,`b`,`c` by 2,3,4,5,6, ... and at the end of every loop check if you have already reached `n`.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate with a program

Comment: why everyone has downvoted my question .Even though my question is good. PLease take back your downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a mathematical solution.

Number of numbers divided by a is `[n/a]`. (`[]` is a floor function.)

And about `b`, `c`, `lcm(a, b)`, `lcm(a, c)`, `lcm(b, c)`, `lcm(a, b, c)` so is it. (lcm means least common multiple.)

So the answer should be

```
([n/a]+[n/b]+[n/c])-([n/lcm(a,b)]+[n/lcm(a,c)]+[n/lcm(b,c)])+[n/lcm(a,b,c)]
```

[image]

Comment: Please format your answer better so that it is easier to understand! Right now it looks like a big jumble of randomness.

Comment: The floor function is implied with integer division.

Comment: Can test-implement your solution?

Comment: @dbush, thank you for revising and I will do my best on stackoverflow.

Comment: Case that (n,a,b,c)=(31,6,10,15), (31/6+31/10+31/15)-(31/30+31/30+31/30)+31/30=8. And they are 6,10,12,15,18,20,24 and 30.

Comment: Thank you for all! I am first at stackoverflow and hope many helps from you all! Regard.

Comment: This is the generic answer when a,b,c are not necessarily co-primes. And coding lcm left as an exercise to the reader...

Answer (score 4):

Given just n and a, there are n/a numbers divisible by a.

Given n, a and b, there are A=n/a and B=n/b numbers divisible by either -- and AB=n/(a*b) divisible by both. The solution would be A+B-AB.

Continuing to three separate numbers, there would be A+B+C-AB-BC-CA+ABC numbers divisible by any of them and omitting duplicates.